# How to add custom tab on Magento back-end product page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I'm looking for the way to add a custom tab in the backend product page, and then display a product grid like Upsell or related product tabs usable by my custom extension.

Thank you for your replies !

Alex
(France)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with product attributes, but I don't think it will let you add a grid. You're going to probably have to start overwriting core Blocks, using Magento's overwriting mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
Indeed I think that I have to overwrite core Blocks, but if anyone have some tips or  examples because it looks a tough work.